# Can I use StackDriver Trace PHP application in GKE?

Tags: cakephp, stackdriver, google-cloud-platform, zipkin

I want to check latencies of RPC every day about CakePHP Application each endpoints running in GKE cluster. I found it is possible using [php google client](https://cloud.google.com/trace/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/patchTraces) or [zipkin server](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/zipkin) by reading documents , but I don't know how easy to introduce to our app though both seem tough for me.

In addition, I'm concerned about GKE cluster configuration has StackDriver Trace option though our cluster it sets disabled.Can we trace span if it sets enable?

Could you give some advices?

Comment: Maybe it seems easy by using php google client because it has class wrapping trace and span parameters. It can use only adding code for setting and send params to before_filter and after_filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded to send gcp's trace api in php client via REST. It can see trace set by php client parameters , but my endpoint for trace api has stopped though I don't know why.Maybe ,it is not still supported well because the document have many ambiguous expression so, I realized watching server response by BigQuery with fluentd and DataStudio and it seem best solution because auto span can be set by table name with yyyymmdd and we can watch arbitrary metrics with custom query or calculation field.